# Pyspark - Merge consecutive duplicate rows but maintain start and end dates

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following format...

```
id , name, start_date, end_date  , active
1  , albert   , 2019-08-14, 3499-12-31, 1
1  , albert   , 2019-08-13, 2019-08-14, 0
1  , albert   , 2019-06-26, 2019-08-13, 0
1  , brian   , 2018-01-17, 2019-06-26, 0
1  , brian   , 2017-07-31, 2018-01-17, 0
1  , albert   , 2017-03-31, 2018-07-31, 0
2  , diane   , 2019-07-14, 3499-12-31, 1
2  , diane   , 2019-06-13, 2019-07-14, 0
2  , ethel   , 2019-03-20, 2019-06-13, 0
2  , ethel  , 2018-01-17, 2019-03-20, 0
2  , frank   , 2017-07-31, 2018-01-17, 0
2  , frank   , 2015-03-21, 2018-07-31, 0
```

And I want to merge consecutive rows where name is the same as the previous row, but maintain the correct start and end dates in the final output dataframe. So the correct output would be...

```
id , name, start_date, end_date  , active
1  , albert   , 2019-06-26, 3499-12-31, 1
1  , brian   , 2017-07-31, 2019-06-26, 0
1  , albert   , 2017-03-31, 2018-07-31, 0
2  , diane   , 2019-06-13, 3499-12-31, 1
2  , ethel   , 2018-01-17, 2019-06-13, 0
2  , frank   , 2017-03-31, 2018-01-17, 0
```

The number of entries per id varies as does the number of different names per id.

How could this be achieved in pyspark?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `df.groupby(["name", "start_date", "end_date"]).sum("active")`?

If I understood your questions right, the above code will do the job.

Comment: yes, but sometimes the name column has the same names separated by a different name. So in say 2016 it might be a, in 2017 it becomes b, but then reverts back to a in 2018.

Comment: Then you should create an identifier for those, and mark all the same `names` with some kind of a unique `id`, and then add them to the `groupby` call.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of thinking I figured out how to do this. There may be a better way, but this works.

First create a window, partitioned by id and ordered by start_date and capture the next row.

```
frame = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(col('start_date').desc())
df = df.select('*', lag(col('name'), default=0).over(frame).alias('next_name'))
```

Then if the current name row and next names match set 0 else set 1...

```
df = df.withColumn('countrr', when(col('name') == col('next_name'), 0).otherwise(1))
```

Next create an extension of the frame to take the rows between the start of the window and the current row, and sum the count col for the frame...

```
frame2 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy(col('start_date').desc()).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = df.withColumn('sumrr', sum('countrr').over(frame2)
```

This effectively creates a column that increases by one when name changes. Finally you can use this new sumrr column and the other columns to group by and take the max and min dates as required...

```
gb_df = df.groupby(['id', 'name', 'sumrr'])
result = gb_df.agg({'start_date':'min', 'end_date':'max'})
```

Then you have to join back the active flag on id, name and end_date.

Gives the correct output...